# Will a default parameter of a function be overwritten when calling the function with other value as parameter?

Tags: delphi, parameters

I'm making a function in Delphi that needs a specific value as parameter, unless it is set when function is called. While te default parameter be overwritten in that case?

example:

```
function ExampleFunction(b = 3, a){
  b*a = c
}
```

```html
ExampleFunction(15,2)
```

Will the default parameter(3) be replaced with the given parameter(15)?

Comment: Your example is not a valid Object Pascal code. Hard to say what you're asking, but [`you can do this`](http://pastebin.com/PsfGGNyn) in Delphi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code does not compile. Its syntax is invalid. It looks rather as though you have written the code in some hybrid of Pascal and C#. I suggest that you fix the question.

What's more, default parameters must appear last in the list. The reason for that is that default parameters allow you to omit an parameter when calling the function. When you do that, the compiler substitutes the missing parameter with the default value. Because parameters are positional, it is not possible to omit a parameter, but then pass another parameter that appears after it in the list.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Default_Parameters), which I urge you to read one more time, says:

> Parameters with default values must occur at the end of the parameter list. That is, all parameters following the first declared default value must also have default values.

Now to the question. If you do not omit the parameter, that is if you provide it, then the value you provided is used.

Let's use an example that actually compiles:

```
function Test(a: Integer; b: Integer = 42): Integer;
begin
  Result := a * b;
end;
```

Then

```
Test(2) = 84 // parameter b is omitted, default value passed
```

and

```
Test(4, 3) = 12
```

Comment: Exactly the answer is needed, code didn't compile because I just made in the code snipped as example.